# Copy formula across columns

Tags: excel, copy

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns : A, B, C, D.

I want to calculate the difference between A-B and C-D.  So in cell E2  I enter  the formula =A2-B2 , and  get the result that I want, which is the difference between A-B.

Now I drag the formula in E2 to cell F2, expecting that Excel will "think" that now I want the difference between C-D.  However, when I drag the formula from column E to column F I get =B2-C2 (you see, Excel assumes I want to use B2 again).

My question is: how can I make Excel “understand” that I want to use =C2-D2 after =A2-B2, and NOT =B2-C2?

This an abbreviated example. The original data-set has hundred of columns. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way in the UI that you get Excel to "think" that much - it'll only shift the references by one column if you drag it across. If deleting the columns in between is not an option, you need to rewrite you formula, e.g.:

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,COLUMN(L1)-COLUMN($L1))-OFFSET(B1,0,COLUMN(L1)-COLUMN($L1))
```

In this example, it is assumed that you start showing the difference in column L - of course you need to adjust according to your worksheet - but once done, you can drag the formula to the right as far as you need.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I really appreciate it.  This solved my problem. I'll learn more about this OFFSET function. Can I please bother you and ask you about the formula? How does it do the trick?

Comment: Your're welcome (also to SO - don't forget to upvote! ;-) )! `OFFSET(R,X,Y)` does what the name indicates: it offsets a cell (or range) R by X rows and Y columns. `COLUMN(R)` returns you the column number of the cell R. Therefore, `COLUMN(L1)-COLUMN($L1)` will return me 0 (and therefore offset the original cell by 0 columns), but become 1 in the M1, as the formula then reads `COLUMN(M1)-COLUMN($L1)`. Thus, not only is A1 shifted by Excel to B1 - but in addition shifted one column furhter by OFFSET. HTH

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter Formula in E2
2. Drag the formula up till G2. Now G2 will have the formula which you want.
3. Delete Col F. Now Col G will move to Col F, which will have your required formula

Comment: Thanks Siddharth...I could do this, but the problem is that I have to calculate differences for hundreds of columns.

Comment: Excel by default will assume that you want to use B2 again (as in the above scenario) if you copy formulas across

Answer (score 0):

As your original data-set has hundreds of columns, you may want to use a non-volatile formula, eg:

`=INDEX(A1:K1,1+COLUMN(L1)-COLUMN($L1))-INDEX(A1:K1,2+COLUMN(L1)-COLUMN($L1))`

This will speed up calculations in the workbook. Depending on how big the data-set is and how many other formulas are in the workbook, the difference in speed could be enormous.

The same conditions apply as in Peter's example.